# html anchor tag - download attribute doesnt download pdf on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf, download, anchor

I m using html anchor tag with download attribute in following way

```
<a href="assets/documents/White and Black Minimalist Resume.pdf" download>Resume</a>
```

but when clicked on link it is redirecting to href url instead of downloading
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: spacing in href might couse this ? -- what happens if you try : "assets/documents/White-and-Black-Minimalist-Resume.pdf"

Comment: my above code works, i checked after hosting on github, the problem was when testing locally it was not downloading instead redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`<a href="./directory/yourfile.pdf" download="newfilename">Download the pdf</a>`

hopefully, this will work.